# Regex for any characters including new lines in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I need a regular expression like `([.\n]*)` but that doesn't work. I have tried the `s` modifier also...

I want to get data from a table and the regular expression which is working in a few cases is:

```
~m/>(@ARGV)<\/.*\n(<td.*\n*.*\/td>\n){3}<td(.*\n*.*\n*)<\/td>/
```

I need to use the `$3`, but the number of newlines is not  defined and I have no idea how could I solve this problem. Can someone please help me?

Comment: A `.` matches any character with an `/s` modifier. Not `[.\n]` that matches a dot and a line feed.

Comment: Do not use regexp to parse HTML/XML.  That way lies madness and extreme code brittleness.  Use a real HTML/XML parser to extract the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. One more question... I need to write code with a maximum length of 160 characters, do you think it is possible if I use a parser for extracting the data I need?

Comment: Please say more about what you're trying to do. Why are you limited to 160 characters?

Comment: Why can your code only be 160 characters? Is this code golf?

Comment: It is a home assignment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find `~m` and `@ARGV` in your test string. So, I made another pattern:

```
<td>((?:<span.*\n*){3})</td>
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO.**](https://regex101.com/r/vH9tY4/6)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I don't know exactly the number of newlines, it can be 0 or more. I tried to write * and {0,} too instead of the {7} like you did.

[here is the sample data](https://regex101.com/r/vH9tY4/3)

Comment: Now the capturing group is in $1. Is that okay?

Comment: I used a part of the original version and this one and it's okay now, thank you.

Comment: I also made version 7 for unknown number of new lines. Please check if it helps